# DropBox without proprietary software

Tags: dropbox, open-source

Is there a way to upload files to a [DropBox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dropbox_(service)) account, and to later retrieve those files from the same DropBox account:

- without making those files public; and
- without requiring a GUI; and
- without requiring any [proprietary (nonfree) software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.html) on the client computer?

If so, what is it?

Comment: You could write something with their API, no? Owncloud iirc can mount a dropbox.

Comment: Maybe [Orphilia](https://github.com/ksiazkowicz/orphilia-dropbox) would solve this. I haven't tried it. Anyone reading who has, feel free to write it up as an answer!

Answer (score 0):

Update: for anyone finding this in a web search, I would now suggest using NextCloud and Disroot.org, instead of OC and OMB.

You could use ownCloud instead. The server-side software is AGPLv3, and there is a [CLI client](https://doc.owncloud.org/desktop/2.1/advancedusage.html) that is [GPL](https://github.com/csawyerYumaed/pyOwnCloud/blob/master/LICENSE). If you don't have your own server, or you're in a hurry, you can set up a gratis account at OpenMailBox.org which includes access to their ownCloud server. OMB use only free software, as confirmed by the FSF on their 'Free Software Webmail Systems' page.

Comment: Thanks. ownCloud and OMB seem great for what they do, but this doesn't really answer my question.

Comment: Sorry I didn't respond to this at the time, but was there a reason you specifically needed to use DropBox, instead of a DB-a-like that doesn't depend on proprietary software? For the record, more info in the OP about why DB is specifically required might have resulted in better answers.

Comment: strypey, I appreciate your good intentions. However, the question is specifically about using the DropBox service in a particular way. It is *not* a request for alternatives to the DropBox service. That being so, the reason why *I* needed to find this out (a) is literally not germane to the question, and (b) would not pass the "[Make it relevant to others](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)" test. I hope you understand. Thanks again.

Comment: Fair enough :) Looks like the answer to your question, sadly, is "no".

Answer (score -3):

Yes, Dropbox does that. Make your folder, add the info and only give the access to the file to the person you want to see it. I set a time limit and remove it or change the name. If you mean hide the folder from sight, I'm not sure about that.

Comment: Does this not require installing proprietary software from DropBox?